# How to get all values (of particular column) of a lookup value in a single cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have headers (dptype, day, batchtimings).how to get multiple (day and batch-timings values) of an individual lookup value in a single cell of another sheet?
**Example:**

```
Dp type  |  day        |batchtimings  
---------|-------------|----------------
 a       |  Saturday   |    10-11
 b       |  friday     |    11-12
 a       |  monday     |    01-02
 y       |  tuesday    |    02-03
 b       |  sunday     |    04-05
 a       |  wednesday  |    04-07
 c       |  sunday     |    03-04
 a       |  friday     |    10-12
 v       |  monday     |    10-11
 b       |  thursday   |    11-12
 y       |  monday     |    09-10
```

I want individual dptype's all the day and batch timings values in a single cell (unique)

**I want-example**:

```
dp type    batches
------------------------------
        |    Saturday:10-11
  a     |    monday :1-2
        |    wednesday:4-7
        |    friday:10-12
--------|--------------------       
  b     |    friday:11-12
        |    Sunday:4-5
        |    thursday:11-12
--------|--------------------
  y     |    tuesday:2-3
        |    monday:9-10
```

Answer (score 1):

Get your list of Unique Types:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A12)
```

Then reference those with:

```
=join(char(10),UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B&":"&text(C:C,"mm-dd"),A:A=F1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
=IFNA( JOIN (" :"), FILTER(B1:C10, A1:A10="A"))
```

Where you would replace the value at the end with what your looking for

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>""))), TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(
 QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE({A2:C, B2:B&":"&TO_TEXT(C2:C)}), 
 "select max(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0),,999^99)), " ", CHAR(10)))})
```

[image: 0]